# javascript radio button value get null

Tags: javascript

In the javascript, I have the pointer to get the name of the fruit. But the alert always shows null.
I checked my logic but unable to find the problem. Any suggestions? thanks!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>My Fruit</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkFruit(){
            var fruit_radio_pointers = document.querySelector('[name="fruit"]'); 
            var which_fruit = null;
            for(var i=0; i<fruit_radio_pointers.length; i++){
                if(fruit_radio_pointers[i].checked){
                    which_fruit = fruit_radio_pointers[i].value;  
                    break;            
                }    
            }
            alert(which_fruit);
        }

        //document.getElementById("my_btn").addEventListener("click", checkFruit, false);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>
        <input name="fruit" type="radio" value="apple" /> Apple<br />
        <input name="fruit" type="radio" value="cherry" /> Cherry
    </p>
    <p>
       <button id="my_btn" onclick="checkFruit()" >Which Fruit?</button>

    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll):

```
var fruit_radio_pointers = document.querySelectorAll('[name="fruit"]');
```

[`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector) only returns the first found match (not as an array).
It is equal to `document.querySelectorAll('[name="fruit"]')[0]`.
As you may have figured out, `querySelectorAll` returns all of the found matches as an array.

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/J7zrv/)

Comment: I just noticed I didnt get reputation for those up votes...I call bull.